# How to get Navigation commands, like left or right in 50 meters

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, gps

I want to create something like Google glasses and I want it to have a navigation displayed. The App only needs the information in which direction I need to turn and how many meters I need to pass until I need to change my direction. Is that somehow possible?

LG Silvinator